# Dynamically export data from .mdb to .mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ms-access

There is **MDB on a local machine**, is it possible somehow to **synchronize MYSQL database on server** with MDB on local machine dynamically? I've used applications that convert MDB to SQL but is it possible to do this with any server side language?

Comment: edit and improve your question please! It's too broad to give an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer to your question is obviously yes, but you probably don't want to.

You can either use [ASP.Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hktw939c(v=vs.85).aspx) or JSP with [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) to read .mdb files using a server-side language (well, any language that can run on a server is server side, but I guess you mean a language that outputs HTML and runs inside a webserver). Obviously, you would need to upload the local file to the server, as the server can't access your local files.

A more sensible way to do this would be to create linked tables in your Access database that link to the data in your MySQL database using ODBC. That way, your data is always synchronized.